# Powers containing every digit equally often

Tags: number-theory, exponentiation

There are several nontrivial powers containing every digit equally often, for example

$32043^2$ $2158479^3$ $69636^4$ $643905^5$ $3470187^6$

A necessary condition for a power with the desired property is that the base is
 divisible by $3$ because the power must be a multiple of $9$.

My questions :

- Are there powers of $3$,$6$ and $9$ with the desired property ?
- Are there infinite many nontrivial powers with the desired property ?
- I did not find a $10th$ power with the desired property yet. Is there one ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a $\frac{1}{3}$th of an answer.
There is an 10th power with the property. Here is a list of the smallest solutions for a given power:

Edit to keep the post small, see Jeppes comment for a list up to 24:

- 10:  81785058

Comment: Thank you for your efforts.

Comment: See more at Sloane's [A074205](https://oeis.org/A074205).

Comment: Very good link, except the annyoing and obtrusive donation appeal ...

Comment: ha, should have known that the sequence is already in OEIS ...

Answer (score 4):

This is not a proof, but a heuristic argument.

Of the $10^{10m} - 10^{10m-1}$ positive integers with $10m$ digits, 
$\dfrac{9}{10} \dfrac{(10m)!}{m!^{10}} \approx \dfrac{9}{32 \sqrt{5}} m^{-9/2} 10^{10m}$ have all digits equally often.  Now the number of $k$'th powers with $10m$ digits is approximately
$(1 - 10^{-1/k}) 10^{10m/k}$, so  we should expect the number of $k$'th powers with $10m$ digits and the desired property to be on the order
of $ m^{-9/2} 10^{10m/k}$. In particular, for any $k$ there should be infinitely many $k$'th powers with the property.